# is there another way of loading extra packages in workers (parallel computing)?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, package

One way of parallelization in R is through the [snowfall](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snowfall/index.html) package. To send custom functions to workers you can use `sfExport()` (see Joris' post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856245/scoping-problem-when-sfapply-is-used-within-function-package-snowfall-r)).

I have a custom function that depends on functions from non-base packages that are not loaded automagically. Thus, when I run my function in parallel, R craps out because certain functions are not available (think of the packages spatstat, splancs, sp...). So far I've solved this by calling library() in my custom function. This loads the packages on the first run and possibly just ignores on subsequent iterations. Still, I was wondering if there's another way of telling each worker to load the package on first iteration and be done with it (Or am I missing something and each iteration starts as a tabula rasa?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a specific command for that in snowfall, `sfLibrary()`. See also  ?"snowfall-tools". Calling library manually on every node is strongly discouraged. sfLibrary is basically a wrapper around the solution Dirk gave based on the snow package.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand the question.

Packages are loaded via `library()`, and most of the parallel execution functions support that. For example, the [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/package=snow) package uses

```
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(boot))
```

to 'quietly' (ie not return value) evaluate the given expression---here a call to `library()`---on each node.  Most of the parallel execution frameworks have something like that.

Why again would you need something different, and what exactly does not work here?

Comment: Thank you Dirk for taking time to look @ my question. I have modified the second paragraph and hopefully it's clearer now what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Correct when using snow, but when using snowfall, it's strongly discouraged to call library() on each node manually. The correct command for that is sfLibrary(), which is afaik basically a wrapper around your solution.

Comment: I guess there was a reason I prefer snow over snowfall :)  It also fits better into the doXXX framework and the foreach package.