# Calling functions from non-base R packages in `parallel` package without librarying them within the function

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Lets say I'm trying to run the following code

```
library(gregmisc)
library(parallel)
myfunction <- function(x){
  combinations(10, x, 1:10)
}
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))
parLapply(cl, 3, myfunction)
```

I'm getting the error

```
#Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
#one node produced an error: could not find function "combinations"
```

So if I'll library "gregmisc" package within the function it will work

```
myfunction <- function(x){
  library(gregmisc)
  combinations(10, x, 1:10)
}
cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))
parLapply(cl, 3, myfunction)
```

**The question is, how can I avoide librarying packages within the function?**

I saw similar questions were asked already re "snow" and "snowfall" in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077069/is-there-another-way-of-loading-extra-packages-in-workers-parallel-computing) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856245/scoping-problem-when-sfapply-is-used-within-function-package-snowfall-r)

but I couldn't get it to work for the "parallel" package

I've tried (without success)

```
library(snow)
library(snowfall)
sfExport(list=list("combinations"))
sfLibrary(gregmisc)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(gregmisc))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any `combinations` function in **gregmisc**. Could that be your actual problem?

Loading packages on each node with `clusterEvalQ()` should work, and always has worked for me.
The following code is lifted nearly verbatim from page 8 of `vignette("parallel")`:

```
require(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
junk <- clusterEvalQ(cl, library(boot)) ## Discard result
```

Comment: sorry, it's in `gtools` package, `gregmisc` package is just automatically calling `gtools`

Comment: You are right, I've accidentally called the wrong library with `clusterEvalQ()`. I'll edit your answer so it will fit the question exactly

Comment: @DavidArenburg I rolled back your edits so that: (1) the code continues to match the text; and (2) the response to the actual core of your question (how to load packages on each of a cluster's nodes) continues to stand out. I'm confident folks can generalize well enough to see how this would apply in your specific case!

Comment: I have tried using this solution

`> require(parallel)`
`> cl <- makeCluster(5)`
`> clusterEvalQ(cl, library(mice))`

However I get the error:

`Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: package ‘lattice’ could not be loaded`

Have you any idea what may be the issue @JoshO'Brien?

Comment: @AP30 Not really. My first step, though, would be to figure out which nodes are throwing the errors, and to then log into one of them to so that I could poke around interactively to figure out which piece of the setup there is causing the problem. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

The environment is not the same in the individual nodes. Try specifying the package explicitly:

```
myfunction <- function(x){
  gregmisc::combinations(10, x, 1:10)
}
```

Comment: Did you actually mean to write `gregmisc::combinations` ?

Comment: Oops, I wrote that from my phone

Comment: Is there an R interpreter for iPhone?